# "Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset" Binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I checked other posts and answers and didn't find a favorable answer. :(

I am trying to find a proper price after a value is generated by code.

For example, I'm trying to place a STOP MARKET order for a MARKET BUY order whose "avgPrice" I already have derived.

I calculated stop loss from that avgPrice, which gives me **37460.830500000004** - I passed this value into Futures STOP MARKET order, and I got this error: **Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset**

```
client.futures_create_order(
    symbol=config.SYMBOL,
    type='STOP_MARKET',
    side='SELL',
    stopPrice=stoploss_price,
    closePosition='True'
)
```

I know that's not the right price to enter - my question is how do I properly round this price for a specific symbol (which are bound to change) automatically?